# How can I toggle class only for clicked element

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I dont know how to toggle class only for clicked element. How can I point out for react that I want to change class only for clicked element. How shall I do it ?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class RecipesList extends Component {
  state = {
    hasClass: false
  };
  toggleActive = () => {
    this.setState({
      hasClass: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { recipesList } = this.props;
    const { hasClass } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul className="recipiesList">
        {recipesList.map(item => (
          <li
            className={hasClass ? "active" : ""}
            key={item.recipe_id}
            onClick={this.toggleActive}
          >
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipesList;
```

Comment: one state variable for multiple elements? use id instead of boolean - save id, compare in loop - assuming only one can be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need an state, let's call it `activeItemId` that store the id (here recipe_id) of the selected item. then you have to change className like this `className={this.state.activeItemId === item.recipe_id ? 'active' : ''}` and this helps us give the `active` class only to the selected item. Then all you have to do is to pass `recipe_id` to toggleActive function (`onClick={() => this.toggleActive(item.recipe_id)}`) and change it to this:

```
toggleActive = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    activeItemId: id
  });
};
```

So every time you click on an item its `id` get stored in `activeItem` state and the item `className` changes to '`active`' cause its recipe_id is equal to activeItemId.

So all together:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class RecipesList extends Component {
  state = {
    activeItemId: null
  };
  toggleActive = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      activeItemId: id
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { recipesList } = this.props;
    const { activeItemId } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul className="recipiesList">
        {recipesList.map(item => (
          <li
            className={activeItemId === item.recipe_id ? "active" : ""}
            key={item.recipe_id}
            onClick={() => this.toggleActive(item.recipe_id)}
          >
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipesList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're using a single flag for all of your items. If you want a flag per item, two choices:

1. Make the items components with state, and have them handle the click.
2. Use a map of flags keyed by the recipe ID

#### #1 Using a `Recipe` component with its own state:

```
class Receipt extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {active: false};
        this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this);
    }
    toggleActive() {
        this.setState(({active}) => ({active: !active}));
    }
    render() {
        const {active} = this.state;
        const {id} = this.props;
        return <li
            className={active ? "active" : ""}
            key={id}
            onClick={this.toggleActive}
            />;
    }
}

class RecipesList extends Component {
  state = {
    hasClass: false
  };
  toggleActive = () => {
    this.setState({
      hasClass: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { recipesList } = this.props;
    const { hasClass } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul className="recipiesList">
        {recipesList.map(item => <Recipe id={item.recipe_id} />)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

#### #2 Using a map:

```
class RecipesList extends Component {
  state = {
    active: new Map()
  };
  toggleActive = (id) => {
    this.setState(({active}) => {
        active = new Map(active);
        active.set(id, !active.get(id));
        return {active};
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { recipesList } = this.props;
    const { hasClass } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul className="recipiesList">
        {recipesList.map(item => (
          <li
            className={hasClass ? "active" : ""}
            key={item.recipe_id}
            onClick={this.toggleActive.bind(null, item.recipe_id)}
          >
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can useState to set the new value when click. I prefer do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
numbers =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

 const [numbers, setNumber] = useState(1)


<div>
   {numbers.map((num, i) => {
     return <Component key={i} value={num} isSelected={selected} onClick= 
    {() => setNumber(num)} />
     })}
</div>
```